# Javascript next and previous day function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a daily calendar and need to traverse to the next and previous day.  How would I write this in javascript?  Will the following calculate correctly when going to the next / previous month?  Like C#'s DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) will?

```
new Date(year, month, day + 1)
```

My concern is that if I execute this on March 31st, it will calculate March 32nd...which wouldn't work obviously.

If someone could provide a function to do both that would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just try it out?

Comment: You know on most modern browsers there is a developers console where you can just type `new Date(2011,2,32)` and see what happens.

Comment: why waste people's time with "what if" ... take less time to test it than to create a post

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var dateString = '30 Apr 2010'; // date string
var actualDate = new Date(dateString); // convert to actual date
var newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(), actualDate.getMonth(), actualDate.getDate()+1); // create new increased date
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry. **[It won't.](http://jsfiddle.net/BH85t/)**

```
date = new Date(2012, 2, 31 + 1);
console.log(date);
```