# next day of a date in javascript with default js functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to get next date of a given date in "yyyymmdd" format with default java script or jquery functions?

Comment: Look at this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927419/javascript-next-and-previous-day-function

Comment: If I were you I would use a date library. Is a few tens of kilobytes really a deal breaker?

Comment: but my date is not in string format. (Its like  19890831 for 31 Aug 1989).@Erwin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've specified jQuery UI you can use its built-in date formatter to get the required output.

The use of the regexp and `new Date` shown below is to guarantee that the vagaries of date parsing don't affect the result.

```
function getTomorrow(dateStr) {
    var ymd = dateStr.match(/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/);
    if (ymd) {
        var date = new Date(ymd[1], ymd[2] - 1, ymd[3]);
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
        return $.datepicker.formatDate('yymmdd', date);
    } else {  // parse error
        return null;
    }
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/R8awH/

Comment: @HarishAnchu oops, I just noticed you said jQuery, not jQuery UI.  Did you already happen to have that, too?

Comment: not a problem. I am already using jquery date picker in my code. @Alnitak

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bit of confusion here.

At the heart of a javascript Date object is the milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 **UTC**. That last bit is very important.

If you create a date by specifying the parts, e.g. for 2 September 2012 (note month number):

```
new Date(2012, 8, 2);
```

then a date object is created for midnight at the start of the date in the local time zone of the host, i.e. 2012-09-02T00:00:00 in the local timezone. However, if you specify a time since epoch, e.g.

```
new Date(1346544000000) // 2012-09-02T00:00:00Z
```

then the date is created at that time **UTC**, so it will show a different local time in different timezones that represents the same time UTC. So if the time is 2012-09-02T00:00:00Z, then in a timezone ten hours ahead of GMT (GMT+10) it will be:

```
2012-09-02T10:00:00+1000
```

If the timezone is six hours behind GMT (GMT-06) it will be:

```
2012-09-01T18:00:00-0600
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Construct the date object, and set the date plus 1.

```
var dateStr = "20120902";
var d = new Date(dateStr.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1/$2/$3'));
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: I set my date to 2012, 09, 30. I expect the output to be Oct 1.

Comment: This is good, but I need output also in the same 'yyyymmdd' format. Thank you.

Comment: @TinaCGHoehr It will be Oct 1.

Comment: My chrome says Sun Sep 30 2012 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

Comment: Also there is a problem with time @xdazz

Comment: @HarishAnchu You could get the year, month, day from the date object.

Comment: @TinaCGHoehr What does `toUTCString()` say?

Comment: This code won't work correctly because the `new Date('yyyy-mm-dd')` line will always set the date for midnight **UTC**.  When you then convert back to "local time" for the western hemisphere you get back the same day you started with.

Comment: @xdazz This doesn't work when you use `-` as the delimiter in the date string, but works fine when you use `/` (because of the problem @alnitak mentioned I suppose)

Comment: K its right. But there is little problem with time. my chrome says Fri Sep 01 1989 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST). In some region this will effect date too. @xdazz

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks, didn't notice that.

Comment: Also note that as far as Mozilla are concerned, `yyyy/mm/dd` is **not** on their list of "understood" formats, and therefore that behaviour is undefined.  The documentation specifies ISO 8601 (i.e. `yyyy-mm-dd`) or RFC822 format.

Comment: @Alnitak—worth noting that IE 8 and lower (and maybe higher) don't support parsing ISO8601 dates but do parse '/' dates, which is one reason why date strings should be parsed manually.

Comment: @RobG yes - even Mozilla only started supporting ISO 8601 with JS 1.85.  Using the constructor that takes each component separately is far less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code:

```
function getnextDay(prevDate) {
  var weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
  prevDate = prevDate.toString();
  var formatteDate = prevDate.substr(0, 4) + ',' + prevDate.substr(4, 2) + ',' + prevDate.substr(6, 2);

  formatteDate = new Date(formatteDate);
  document.write(weekday[formatteDate.getDay() + 1])
}

getnextDay(19890831)​​
```

and
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2Rn9j/)

Comment: Your first 8 lines can (*should*) be replaced by `var weekday = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', etc.]`

Comment: that is not the op's problem here.Optomization can be done later also.

Comment: expected output is 19890901 @AshirvadSingh

Comment: @AshirvadSingh Didn't downvote, just giving you a pointer regarding js best practice. Your choice to follow it or not. :)

Comment: @AshirvadSingh writing the array correctly is not "optimisation".  _Not_ writing it correctly the first time shows lazy programming style and/or a lack of familiarity with the language.

Comment: '*...but I need output also in the same 'yyyymmdd' format*' You should probably have the method return the updated date string. +1 anyway, code works

Comment: @nbrooks no, the code doesn't work.  It doesn't output the right format, and it constructs the `Date` object using an undefined syntax.

Comment: @alnitak that format was specified in a comment on a different post, not in the question. The question also originally read 'next day' rather than 'next date', so the implementation was reasonable. As for the date string being comma-delimited, the browser seems willing to parse it. I don't know if that is strictly within the spec, but if it isn't, maybe you can point us in the right direction?

Comment: @nbrooks comma-separated certainly isn't in the MDN spec.  Chrome seems happy with it, but I would never rely on it.  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty straight forward.

```
var today = new Date();
var date = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()+1);
```

Use moment.js if you extensively use date functionalities.
For just getting the next day, this would suffice.

Answer (score -1):

yes

It is pretty much easy with javaScript as follow:

```
today = new Date().getTime();
tomorrow = today + 24*60*60*1000;
parsed_tomorrow = new Date(tomorrow);
```